# DotNetNuke redirect setting

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have made a mistake, and created a permanent redirection under Host settings to a portal that doesn't exist. Now my site does not work, and there's no way to access it.

Any ideas how to restore that value back to what it was? I have searched the database tables with no luck.

Comment: You might want to ask this on DNN's forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the PortalAliases? You should check both the PortalSettings and PortalAliases table to clean up any remnants, though from the host/site management page you should be able to change those settings without having to navigate to the URL of the portal itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found the answer. In the PortalSettings table the value needs to be changed to the desired value i.e. www.mysite.com